# How to group SQL instances in arrays

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have an SQL table that links students to classes. This table primarily has the ids user_id and class_id. Let's suppose that each user_id is unique to the table but class_ids are not.

I want to retrieve all the instances of user_id and group them by class_id. I also wanted to be able to reprensent the result returned by SQL as the following in PHP:

```
array(
class_id => array(
    user_id => <user info..>,
    user_id => <user info..>,
    user_id => <user info..>
),
class_id => array(
    user_id => <user info..>,
    user_id => <user info..>,
    user_id => <user info..>
),
class_id => array(
    user_id => <user info..>,
    user_id => <user info..>,
    user_id => <user info..>
)
```

)

I know I could call an SQL inject per class and return the users from that class and format the result into the format I need in PHP, but would there be a way to do this in one SQL request as oposed to having to do one request per class (+ 1 request to get the list of class ids)?

It is because I need to access specific classes, so I think that the key/value solution of arrays in PHP are the best way to access classes.

Comment: seems to only give the first instance of each class_id in a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. If you use a LEFT JOIN, you could get one result set with both class info and student info however. it would not be in the exact format above, but would be a pretty simple conversion.

the result set would look like

```
class_id, student_id, student_etc
class_id, student_id, student_etc
class_id, student_id, student_etc
```

there would be one record for each class * number of students taking that class

**to elaborate**

```
classes table
id, etc

users table
id, etc

class_to_users table
id, class_id, user_id
```

then

```
SELECT classes.id, users.id
FROM classes
LEFT JOIN class_to_users ON class_to_users.class_id = classes.id
LEFT JOIN users ON class_to_users.user_id = users.id
WHERE 1
ORDER BY classes.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//assumes SQL was something like
//  SELECT class_id, user_id, user_info FROM users INNER JOIN users_class ON ...
//assumes query result is in $query

$result=array();

while (true) {
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
  if (!$row) break;
  if (!isset($result[$row['class_id']])) $result[$row['class_id']]=array();
  $result[$row['class_id']][$row['user_id']]=$row['user_info'];
}
```

Comment: this does not work, because one student could be taking multiple classes (assumed). I imagine there would need to be a separate table linking students to classes.

Comment: @dqhendricks This should be solved inside the SQL - the PHP code is designed to deal with that. I edited my answer to reflect that in the SQL

Comment: `while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) {` would clean this up a little. `while (true)` loops give me the willies.

Comment: really ?! you really think that it is appropriate to use `mysql_*` functions in 2012 for writing new code ?

Comment: @tereško As allways the code in my answer is ment to be instructive, not productive. Think of `mysql_fetch_array()` as a mental concept, not a function.

Comment: @augustknight Again, instructive, not productive. In addition to that, on a normal day I use 5+ programming languages, all with their tiny differences in semantics, this makes me tick "language-portable", so I think I'd really write it with `while(true)` in many cases. I (have to) use a lot of Pascal, which has no assignment-as-a-value concept, `while variable:=function_call() do begin` would compile-error out.

Comment: @EugenRieck , code in you example is **not instructive** , it is just bad , and if someone learns from your "instructions, then he learns bad practices. **-1**

Comment: @tereško You are welcome to post your own answer - FYI: This site works primarily by providing answers.